# Ubuntu 18.10 installation stuck at Grub2

Tags: grub2, live-usb, 18.10

A neighbour asked me if I could install Ubuntu on his laptop as he didn't know how. It is a HP 3168NGW, and I'm trying to install Ubuntu via a 16GB ADATA UV120 USB2 drive that the neighbour provided, which I turned into a bootable Ubuntu drive on a Late 2011 MacBook Pro as my newer one couldn't read the format and would've also required an male USB-C to female USB-A adapter which I don't have at hand at the moment. I've tried Googling the issue but only answers there are are for way older versions of Ubuntu and can't be done, or just wont work. Any suggestions or more specifics needed?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen At the moment at "Installing package "grub2"...". https://i.imgur.com/UYMqA8l.jpg Sorry about the blurry image, took it in a hurry with an age old phone. The laptop has been at that stage for ~16-20 hours now?